# Get the current application user on a 1 to 1 relationship in MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I'm trying to get an MVC model that is based on the user with a 1 to 1 relationship. **IN THE MAIN _layout.cshtml** file

(where the Application user from identity, and the id from the more user info are the same)

I know that i could get the user by using the USER class, but i dont get the **.Moreinfo** option on it.

is there a way for me to call `User.Moreinfo.address`?

*p.s. i know that i could add all in one model with the application user but i don't want to do it*

Comment: You're better off creating a childaction and a partial view and plumbing it into the `_Layout.cshtml`. What you're requesting would require a DB round-trip (which shouldn't be done in a view).

Comment: thats ok but how do i get the Users related data there?

Comment: my whole navigation is changing based on the Users usage

Comment: Gien the new information, have you looked at MvcSiteMapProvider? You can add customizations based on authentication, roles, etc.

Comment: ok but i still need the more info on the nav.